# Expectation of the fill distance of $N$ random points in $[0,1]^s$

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ be uniformly distributed points in $[0,1]^s, s \in \mathbb{N}$.

What can be said about
$$
\mathbb{E} \left(\sup_{x \in [0,1]^s} \min_{i \in \{1,..N\}} \|x - x_i\|_2 \right)
$$
where $\|y\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^s y_i^2}$ denotes the Euclidian norm.

In other words, what is the diameter of the largest empty ball I can expect to place in $[0,1]^s$.

Comment: That sounds like a probabilistic nightmare, but I am not an expert in the field. Inequalities are probably easier to get, by estimating the inradius of the largest Voronoi cell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ or the circumradius of $(s+1)$-uples. I am expecting that, most of the times, the supremum is attained at a vertex of the hypercube $[0,1]^s$.

Comment: The distribution of the minimum distance is the basis for one of the tests of randomness in the original DieHard suite. IN the original formulation only the lowest order approximant was used, and around the 90's, with the availability of faster computers, the number of variates examined in tests became large enough that this led to false positives. This was fixed, at least in the HEP community, by calculated second order effects arising from wall effects and triple-overlaps. I think that made its was back into improved DIeHard versions.